# "variable" buffer en python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Una pregunta super corta y sencilla de la cual no encontre mucho en internet.

hay una variable al parecer llamada buffer, en sublime text 3  esta se torna de un color azul, porque ocurre esto?

Hay codigos en los que se usa una variable buffer, ¿cual es su cometido?

Comment: provee un [mre] ademas de colocar una imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] en sublime text 3 esta se torna de un color azul, porque ocurre esto?

Porque Sublime Text 3 considera que `buffer` es una palabra "reservada" del lenguaje, es decir, un *builtin* como `print`, `str()` y otros.

Pero esto sólo era así en **Python2**. En Python3 la palabra `buffer` no significa nada especial para el lenguaje y por tanto el editor debería colorearla como cualquier otra variable.

Además, en Python2 `buffer` no sería una variable, sino una función que se usaría para obtener una vista "directa" de los bytes de un objeto (en particular de una cadena), así: `vista = buffer(objeto)`. El cometido de esto es bastante técnico. Básicamente equivale a un array de bytes con la diferencia de que las "rodajas" (ej: `vista[3:10]` no hacen una copia, sino que devuelven otra "vista" usando punteros a los bytes originales.

**En Pyton3 esta función no existe** y se tiene en cambio `memoryview()` para el mismo cometido, si bien no se puede aplicar a cadenas, sino sólo a `bytes` o `bytearray`.

> Hay codigos en los que se usa una variable buffer, ¿cual es su cometido?

En tu caso, debido a que pones la etiqueta Python3, y también debido a que `buffer` es el nombre de una variable y no el de una función, el cometido no tiene nada que ver con lo explicado anteriormente.

Simplemente `buffer` es el nombre que el programador ha decidido darle a esa variable, igual que la podría haber llamado `almacen` o `foo`.

No obstante en informática la palabra *buffer* suele asociarse con un *almacén intermedio* utilizado entre una parte del programa que accede directamente a la entrada/salida (por ejemplo a disco, o teclado, o red), y otra parte del programa que necesita esos datos.

Por ejemplo, una parte del programa puede necesitar ir leyendo del disco los bytes de uno en uno. En cambio, acceder a disco de ese modo sería ineficiente. Entonces, la función de acceso a disco tendría un almacén intermedio con capacidad, digamos por ejemplo, para 512 bytes y cuando se le pide un byte, lee del disco 512 (que es más eficiente pues tardará tanto como leer uno solo), y devolverá sólo el primero. La próxima vez que se le pida "el siguiente byte" no necesita leerlo, pues lo tiene ya en el almacén. Y así para los 511 siguientes. Cuando el almacén se vacíe, leerá del disco otros 512, etc.

Este tipo de almacén intermedio se suele denominar *buffer* y es problable que en el programa que has visto la variable `buffer` tenga este cometido. Aunque no tiene por qué ser necesariamente así. Simplemente es el nombre que el programador decidió poner.

Answer (score 0):

La función buffer() permite accesos directos de los datos sin necesidad de que antes los copie lo que genera ganancias de rendimiento cuando se trata de  objetos muy grandes

```
> >>> S = buffer ( 'Buen día' )
 >>> S
 <búfer de solo lectura para 0x00EE64A0, tamaño -1, desplazamiento 0 en 0x00EE2019>
 >>> imprimir S
 buen día
```

Comment: Pero ¿por qué has traducido el código? En vez de `imprimir` debería ser `print`, y la salida entre `< >` también debería permanecer en inglés.

Comment: Claro que si,pero este es un ejemplo para que lo entienda cualquiera y claro tienes que ponerlo como se escribiría en python en este caso como dices seria con print()